# input type checkbox to be true or false depended on the data

Tags: javascript, html, checkbox

I'm trying to create a checkbox, which is depended on the database to show whether it should be initially checked or unchecked.

Played around the checkedbox and value with true/false, 0/1 and  ""/blanks

```
$.each(customers, (index, customer) => {
$('#accordionAlarm').append(
`<tr>
<td class="card">

<input type="checkbox" name="checkBox[]" id="1${customer.customerId}" checked="${customer.alarmDateInitial === 'Y' ?  'true' : 'false' }"></input>
<input type="checkbox" name="checkBox[]" id="5${customer.customerId}" checked="${customer.alarmDateFifth === 'Y' ?  'true' : 'false' }"></input>
<input type="checkbox" name="checkBox[]" id="7${customer.customerId}" checked="${customer.alarmDateSeventh === 'Y' ?  'true' : 'false' }"></input>

</td>
</tr>`)
});
```

Expected:

- When data = Y, checkbox is checked
- When data != Y, checkbox is not checked

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`checked` is a [boolean attribute](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/common-microsyntaxes.html#boolean-attribute), which means that its mere existence indicates that the element is checked.

You have to restructure your template literal so that `checked` is only included if the condition is `true`, e.g.

```
customer.alarmDateInitial === 'Y' ?  'checked' : ''
```

In context:

```
`<input type="checkbox" name="checkBox[]" id="1${customer.customerId}" ${customer.alarmDateInitial === 'Y' ?  'checked' : '' } ></input>`
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried `checked="checked"` instead of a truthy value? You could also just return `checked` instead of setting the attribute value.